# Issue writing Textview on Second Activity

Tags: java, android, textview

first of all , im sorry for my english , i hope i can express myself well.
I have an app , on the main activity i have 2 numbers i want to send to the second activity and store them in there as a History of these numbers , When i close the app i dont need them anymore , so its just for a temporal use.

In this void i send The numbers to the second class.

```
public void PasarHistorial() {
    ContadorH++;

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,   Historial.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Res1", counter1);
    myIntent.putExtra("Res2", counter2);
    myIntent.putExtra("ContH",ContadorH);
    startActivity(myIntent);


}
```

Second Class ( Historial) :

```
public class Historial extends AppCompatActivity {
public  static TextView H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8, H9;
public int Resultado1,Resultado2,contador;
public Button Regresar;


public void Regresar(){
    Regresar= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Regresar);
    Regresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_historial);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



    H1  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia1);
    H2  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia2);
    H3  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia3);
    H4  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia4);
    H5  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia5);
    H6  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia6);
    H7  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia7);
    H8  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia8);
    H9  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Historia9);
    Regresar();

    int Res1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("Res1",0);
    int Res2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("Res2",0);
    int ContH = getIntent().getIntExtra("ContH",0);
    contador = ContH;
    Resultado1 = Res1;
    Resultado2 = Res2;

    GuardarResultado();

}





public void GuardarResultado() {

                switch (contador) {

                    case 0:
                    break;


       case 1:
          H1.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);
          break;


       case 2:
           H2.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);
           break;
       case 3:
           H3.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;
       case 4:
           H4.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;
       case 5:
           H5.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;
       case 6:
           H6.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;
       case 7:
           H7.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;
       case 8:
           H8.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;
       case 9:
           H9.setText("Resultado :" + Resultado1 + " : " + Resultado2);

           break;


                }


            }
```

}

i did it in this way , becouse i was having the textviews null when calling them on a diferent way.
Now , the issue is that when i call the funcion 1 time , it writes the numbers i need in the place i need , but calling it again , deletes my first result and writes the second.
And even when i go back to the main class and go again to The Historial Class y lose everything.
Im new programming , Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the numbers you can use Sharedpreferences.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("yourint", yourIntValue);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: When i close the app i dont need them anymore , and i think there is something wrong in the codding more than the way i save it .Thanks By the way